# Powershell source control/subversion scenario. Is this even possible?

Tags: svn, powershell, scripting, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm rather new to Subversion/Source Control so I'm wondering if this is even possible.

I have installed a 2012 server that will serve as a central location for all our scripts (mainly Powershell).  It will host production scripts that perform monitoring tasks as well as various other, useful/ad-hoc, scripts that are used by our SysAdmins.

Now, I would like to implement some form of source control/subversion so that we can track changes made to the scripts.  However, I'm not sure if the sort of scenario I want is feasible.

I want have a folder called E:\Scripts where all scripts are stored and executed from.

However, whenever someone wants to change a script in that folder they shouldn't just edit it directly but go via some source control/Subversion tool (e.g. TortoiseSVN).

Now, I've been playing with TortoiseSVN a bit but maybe I'm not understanding how it really works.  I've created a repository (E:\SVN) and added the E:\Scripts folder to it.  I can checkout a script and modify it but when I commit the changes it doesn't update the script in E:\Scripts (I assumed it would, maybe I'm mistaken).

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: It does not have any continous communication with the server, so it won't know that new code has been checked in. After you have checked in your code from a different location you need to execute the svn command to get the latest code from the source code repository (e.g. with TortoiseSvn you could probably just right click the `e:\scripts` folder and click the context menu item to get latest code with TortoiseSvn). I suggest reading a tutorial on svn, which you should probably be able to find easily by searching on your favourite search engine.

Comment: Hmm, I'll search for a tutorial.  Right-clicking on the E:\scripts folder doesn't seem to give me any sort of option to "update from repository"...unless it's Export?  That'll be annoying having to do that every time.  Looks like i need to read up on SVN ;)

Comment: If you have Tortoise SVN installed _and_ the `E:\Scripts` folder content _is the result of a `SVN Checkout`_ you should have an option `SVN Update` which can be used to get the latest version after someone has `SVN Commit` their changes into the source control system.

Comment: Also, TortoiseSVN comes with a command-line executable `svn.exe`, so one could run `Set-Location 'E:\Scripts'; & svn update` in a script.

Comment: You may need to update the way TortoiseSVN is configured to use _shared drives_. By default, TortoiseSVN doesn't work on shared drives because it slows it down. Instead, you should checkout your working directory locally and not share a single working directory between users. That way, when someone checks in a change, you know who checked it in.

Answer (score 1):

We use the exact same setup, source controlling PS scripts and running them from our local copies.

After another developer commits and you want her changes, right click on the  e:\scripts folder and find SVN Update. This will load the latest repository changes to your local copy

[image: svnUpdate]
<sub>(source: [troyworks.com](http://troyworks.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/tortoisesvn_right_click_svn_update.png))</sub>

If you don't have the context menu in the screenshot shown, then you need to install an SVN client on your local machine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. In fact, this is what Source Control is all about...

If you have a Subversion repository, (and you're using either Apache or `svnserve` -- don't use `file:///`!), you can easily do what you want.

I take it that the `E:` drive is shared. There's no need to do that. Instead, each user will have their *working copy* of the Subversion repository. This *working copy* will locally on the user's own system. Simply do a Subversion checkout, and they'll get the latest and greatest versions of all the PowerShell scripts right on their local system. If they make a change, they can commit that change. If they want to get the latest changes, they do a Subversion update. Again, all of this on the local system.

Now, let's take a slightly different scenario. You want these scripts to be on a production server, and the latest up to date versions too. You can use a Continuous Integration system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to help you there.

Jenkins can watch the Subversion repository, and when it detects a change, will update it's own *working copy*. You can place this working copy anywhere. For example, you could have Jenkins checkout the working directory defined on some shared directory that's accessible to all of your servers. When someone changes a script and checks in that change, Jenkins will update it's working copy, and all the servers will automatically get the changes.

Some sites use a special *production* branch. This way, development can take place as usual on trunk for testing, etc. However, when they are ready to install the changes on the server, they merge the changes onto the *production* branch. Their Jenkins server will see the changes, and update its working directory which just happens to be a shared directory that all of the servers have access to.

By the way, PowerShell works nicely with the Subversion command line client. You have the ability to install the Subversion command line client when you install TortoiseSVN. This may be a good way to use PowerShell with Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I've been playing with TortoiseSVN a bit but maybe I'm not understanding how it really works. I've created a repository (E:\SVN) and added the E:\Scripts folder to it. I can checkout a script and modify it but when I commit the changes it doesn't update the script in E:\Scripts (I assumed it would, maybe I'm mistaken).

Here's your problem:

1. You should use `svnserve` which you can setup as a [Windows Service](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.winservice).
2. You should not put the repository on a shared drive. You might want to put it on a separate server. That way, when your machine is turned off, Subversion is still working. A shared drive means that users have access to the raw Subversion repository directory and they can do unspeakable horrors. There's no reason why anyone (except `svnserve`) has access to the raw repository directory.
3. The purpose of Version Control is to give each user their own private working directory. Each user does a checkout on their own machine. Each user does a commit on their own machine. This allows users to share a repository without interfering with each other. If the users share a working directory on a shared drive, they will interfere with each other.

   - User #1 needs to make two changes in file `foo.ps1` and `bar.ps1`.
   - User #2 needs to make a change in file `foo.ps1`.
   - User #1 edits `foo.ps1`, and is now editing `bar.ps1`.
   - User #2 edits `foo.ps1` while user #1 is editing `bar.ps1`.
   - User #2 commits the changes, and ends up committing partial changes in `bar.ps1`. Also, User #2 removes some of the changes in `foo.ps1` because they didn't know what they were for.
   - When things don't work, we have no idea who made what changes.

If each user had their own working directory:

- User #1 makes changes to `foo.ps1` and `bar.ps1`.
- While User #1 makes their changes, User #2 makes the changes in `foo.ps1` and commits. User #2 never saw User #2 changes, and won't try to remove them because they don't know what they're for.
- User #1 is finished and tries to commit their changes. Whoops, the commit fails, and User #1 must update the working directory. They get User #2 changes in `foo.ps1 and can make sure their changes don't interfere with User #2 changes.
- User #1 now commits their changes. We have a complete history of who made what changes.

So...

- Put the Repository **locally**. If you don't want it on your machine, put it on a server. The price of hardware is cheap enough that a machine that does nothing but act as a Subversion server is always in budget and is always a good idea. Virtual machines are even cheaper. If you don't want to use a Windows license on the server due to cost, install Linux. (Just make sure port 3690 isn't being blocked by your routers. That's the port `svnserve` uses by default).
- Run `svnserve` on that server. Touching that raw Subversion repository directory is forbidden and should be unaccessible to everyone except for the Subversion administrator.
- Have each user checkout from Subversion **locally** to their machine. They should not be sharing a working directory ***EVER***.